# How do I check if column is null within query with eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to delete all entries which have not been viewed in the past 30 days and are were created more than 30 days ago.

The column `last_viewed_at`'s default value is `null`, so in case the entry was `created_at` 5 days ago and was not viewed, the row should get not be deleted.

I currently use

```
$medias = Media::where('last_viewed_at', '<=', $delete_after_x_days)->get();
```

This code snippet does not include the scenarios of where a media item was created during the last 30 days and has not been viewed, so should not be deleted just yet.

Somehow, I need to check `created_at` if `last_viewed_at` is null to make sure the media is older than 30 days.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can use in where condition columnName is null

Comment: sorry for this silly comment of mine now, but I don't quite understand. If I just check if the column is null, that would be another query. I need one nested query, that if `last_viewed_at` is empty, then use column `created_at`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I came up with a solution thanks to @knowledge....'s hint.

```
$medias = Media::where('created_at', '<=', $delete_after_x_days)
    ->where(function ($medias) use ($delete_after_x_days) {
        $medias->where('last_viewed_at', '<=', $delete_after_x_days)
            ->orWhereNull('last_viewed_at');
    })
    ->get();
```

This makes sure the entry is older than x days and that `last_viewed_at` is also older than 30 days or is null.

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea in your model how you use but your where condition would look like this,

```
last_viewed_at is not null and last_viewed_at<= $delete_after_x_days
```